# Codeigniter pagination using query strings

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-2

I am trying to implement Codeigniter pagination using query strings but have run into a few issues with this. I've switched on

```
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
```

So to use query strings for pagination but as far as I can see this is really intended to work when you are using query strings for controller and method routing.  However in my case I am still using URI segments for routing but just want to use query strings for pagination, filtering results, search etc. When I try to use http_build_query() to reconstruct the url with the query string sent through it causes the per_page (which I have renamed to offset) to get written twice on any pagination link after the first page.  The reason being that when I recreate the query string offset is already in the $_GET on subsequent pages and CI is also appending it as well causing it to appear twice.  In the code below I've removed the original per_page query string from the $_GET so the query string can be rebuilt without it and CI will add this during the pagination create_links().  I wanted to check if this makes sense or if there is a cleaner way of dealing with this.

```
// load pagination library
$this->load->library('pagination');

// set pagination base url
$config['base_url'] = base_url('accounting/bank/reconcile-account1/account/' . $bank_account_id) . '/?';

// assign current $_GET parameters to local variable as we need to remove offset each time we rebuild query
// string otherwise it gets appended twice to url
$get = $_GET;

// unset the offset array item
unset($get['offset']);

// build first url link
$config['first_url'] = base_url('accounting/bank/reconcile-account1/account/' . $bank_account_id) . '/?' . http_build_query($get);

// if $get contains items then build these back onto the url
if (count($get) > 0) $config['suffix'] = '&' . http_build_query($get);

// set the total number of rows
$config['total_rows'] = $result['total_num_txns'];

// set the number of items per page
$config['per_page'] = $filter->limit;

// initialise the pagination config
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Comment: Why are you using query strings and not using the router ? I am a little unsure as to what you are trying to achieve. A simple solution is to use the router but overload the method so to speak, you can do this by passing default values into the method. If you want to hide the uri from the browser just call the method via ajax

Comment: Because in the past I've run into issues when using uri segments where the number of items per page is always added to the end of the url and I want to send search parameters as key pairs but the per page value appended at the end of the url by Codeigniter is treated as the key when you use uri_to_assoc as it's a single uri segments and doesn't get treated as /per_page/10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [CodeIgniter 3.0](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Pagination.php) version of the Pagination Library. It has a config option to reuse the query string.

I've implemented it myself in a CodeIgniter 2, but rather than replace the distributed version , I deployed it as an overloaded library called MY_Pagination and placed it in my 'application/libraries' folder. The only code change I had to do to make this work this way was to set the access modifiers to public rather than protected.

Comment: I saw that on the CI3 change log.  Going to have a look at this.